# Jquery, default href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a very simple question I know, but I have this jQuery code that has it's own default text. How can I make the following be the default output when the page loads?

```
<li><a href="/panasonic/index.php/site/pictureFeatured" id="featuredProducts" ></a></li>
```

Here's my code

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pav li a").click(function() {
            $("#promocont").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='loading2.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
            $("#pav li a").removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $.ajax({ 
                url: this.href, 
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#promocont").empty().append(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("#featuredProducts").click(function() {
            $('#featuredProducts').css('background-position', '0 -46px');
            $('#mostPopular').css('background-position', '0 0');
        });

        $("#mostPopular").click(function() {
            $('#mostPopular').css('background-position', '0 -46px');
            $('#featuredProducts').css('background-position', '0 0');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="homemid">
    <ul id="pav">
        <li><a href="/panasonic/index.php/site/pictureFeatured" id="featuredProducts" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="page_2.html"  id="mostPopular"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="promocont">
        Deafult Text
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont want a defualt text, I just want

```
<li><a href="/panasonic/index.php/site/pictureFeatured" id="featuredProducts" ></a></li>
```

That to be loaded. I mean the content of that link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

```
$('#promocont').load($('#featuredProducts').attr('href'));
```

Comment: that's done it. thanks, I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.